# What is this error in vs 2013?

Tags: c#

I've got a little code and an error that i can't understand or fix.
Here is the code

```
private list<ConsoleKey> _keyList;

public Reader(ushort clickDelay, list<ConsoleKey> keyList, Action onClick)
{
   _clickDelay = clickDelay;
    ReadThr = new Thread(Read);
   _onClick = new Action(onClick);
   _keyList = new list<ConsoleKey>(keyList);
}
```

the error is :

> Error 1   Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type
>   'KeyReader.list' is less accessible than method
>   'KeyReader.Reader.Reader(ushort, `KeyReader.list<System.ConsoleKey>`,
>   System.Action)'

How do i fix this ?!

Comment: Where do you declare the type `KeyReader.list`?

Comment: ive got no idea it simply doesnt exist

Comment: Maybe you meant to use `List<T>` instead of `list<T>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
list<ConsoleKey>
```

with

```
List<ConsoleKey>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty certain that the source of the error is that you have _keyList declared as private, but using it in a public area.  I don't have time to double-check this, but try changing _keyList from private to public or Reader from public to private (if possible) and see if the error goes away.